# How many distinguishable outcomes from rolling 6 identical dice?

Tags: combinatorics, statistics

Ignoring order, how many distinguishable outcomes are there from rolling 6 identical dice? Answer = $462$

I tried a variety of ways such as $\frac{6^6}{6!}$ and can't seem to get the answer. Struggling how to incorporate no order and distinguishable at the same time. Please help.

Comment: Offhand looks like one might need to consider all the possible partitions of 6.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

An outcome here is the same as a six-tuple of non-negative integers that sum to $6$, the $i^{th}$ entry telling you how many times $i$ came up as a value.

[Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) tell us that the number of such is $$\binom {6+6-1}6=462$$

Comment: Could you explain in more detail please, thank you.

Comment: What part is confusing?  The link contains a detailed proof of the relevant formula.

Comment: Is the bijection clear?  Since the order of the dice doesn't matter, the only thing that distinguishes two different outcomes is the six-tuple.  How many $1's$ did you get?  How many $2's$ and so on.  Thus you just want to count those six-tuples.

Comment: I'm confused as to why it must sum to 6?

Comment: Because there are $6$ dice.

Comment: Say you throw and you get the values $\{1,6,1,1,5,6\}$  We note that you got three $1's$, one $5$ and two $6's$.  Thus your outcome would be the six-tuple $(3,0,0,0,1,2)$. Note that these sum to the total number of dice, namely $6$.

Comment: Okay, thank you I understand now

Comment: It's worth showing that example and saying it would be depicted by `***||||*|**`. So, this problem reduces to "How many distinct ways can we write 6 stars and 6 bars?"

Answer (score 2):

Let $x_1,x_2,...,x_6$ indicate the number of $1,2,3,4,5,6$.

Then the problem can be formulated as:
$$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5+x_6=6, 0\le x_i\le 6.$$

For example, the following outcomes are equivalent:
$$111112\equiv 111121\equiv 111211\equiv 112111\equiv 121111 \Rightarrow \\
(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,x_6)=(5,1,0,0,0,0);\\
111123\equiv 111213\equiv 112113\equiv 121113\equiv \cdots\equiv 321111 \Rightarrow \\
(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,x_6)=(4,1,1,0,0,0);\\$$

Using Stars and Bars method:
$${6+6-1\choose 6-1}=462.$$